# Click through transparent window in Xlib

Tags: c, graphics, transparent, xlib

I would like to be able to draw anywhere on the screen, so I think I should create a transparent, fullscreen, undecorated window.

The problem is, all events pass through the window.  I'd like to catch a mouse-move event and use it.

Any ideas?  Might I be able to do this in a higher-level library?

Answer (score 0):

Simply take a screen capture and make a full screen window filled with those pixels. You won't get live update but you will be able to process the mouse and keyboard events however you like.